# Getting an error while dealing with Decision Tree fitting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I used a dataframe on which I'm applying a Decision Tree Classifier, but it is showing me following error :

could not convert string to float: ' mood_swings, weight_loss, weight_loss'

My code is :

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

Comment: I read this comment today "I think you can use ML for literally anything as long as you can convert it into numbers and program it to find patterns. Literally, it could be anything any input or output from the universe" In short you have to convert that categorical data to numbers else it won't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Usually, these errors come from None/NaN types inside your columns. Make sure there are no Na's and that your columns that should have strings contain only strings.